# Transform http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd to C# class using xsd.exe tool not working

Tags: c#, class, xsd

I wanted to do C# class from http://www.loc.gov/standards/mets/mets.xsd which is METS: Metadata Encoding and Transmission Standard.

But when I used the transformation tool `xsd.exe /c mets.xsd`, then I get warnings about several attributes which are not declared, and class creation failed.

I really need to get this class because I need it to serialize objects of this type to XML.

Screenshot of xsd.exe is here:

[image: xsd.exe failure]

Comment: I'm mostly guessing as I have no idea what the error messages are telling you, but could it be [this problem](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/joselcs/2004/03/30/support-of-import-in-xsd-exe/), ie xsd needs to be called with not only the schema you want to convert, but also those refereed to by that schema?

Comment: Welcome to [so].Codes should be added as `code blocks` and not as images. That makes it searchable and readability increases too.

Comment: Thanks for comment, i tried to add schema xlink.xsd(i got it from schema location) which wrote warnings and now it is ok, so i added it: xsd.exe /c mets.xsd xlink.xsd and class is generated. Petr

Comment: May I suggest you formulate the steps needed to get to a solution as an answer, and accept your own answer? That's standard practice here on SO and it will make the question more valuable to future visitors, the green acceptance checkmark makes it clear that a working solution to the problem exists.